# Prevent preflight request from internal redirect

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios

I am working on a web application, both the backend and the frontend are hosted on different endpoints on an internal PaaS, which redirects to a SSO page if any request coming to it doesn't have the authenticated cookie.

When I send a GET request from the frontend to the backend, it also passes through the cookies (with credentials in axios). But when I make a POST request, the browser first makes a preflight OPTIONS request without cookie and internally the backend service redirects to the SSO, as a result it never gets to sending the POST request at all.

The preflight request by design exclude user credentials, how can I get around it?

Answer (score 1):

Write a middleware in your backend, top in the heirarchy and check the request type in it.

if it is "OPTIONS", just verify the origin, if it is familiar respond right away with 200 instead of passing control to next, if not then respond with 403

if it is not "OPTIONS", just pass the control to next so that it deals accordingly

assuming a node-express server, the middleware would look like this

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
  if(req.method==='OPTIONS' && whiteListUrls.includes(req.origin)){
    res.status(200);
  }else{
    next();
  }
})
```